# How to make this as a HighChart (picture attached)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, range

Highchart experts!  I'd like to make the following chart (using the Highcharts framework) and don't know where to begin. Do I overlay several charts into one?  How would I create boxes with the ranges as pictures in the attached example?  Anyone have any examples out there?

[image: example chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `columnrange` series type with two stacked series. The first series will present column from min to mid, the second mid to max. To plot dots use another series type `scatter`. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange'
  },
  xAxis: [{
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
  }, {
   visible: false,
   min: 0,
    max: 100
  }],
  yAxis: {
   min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  plotOptions: {
   series: {
     stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
   id: 'main',
    name: 'Grades',
    data: [
      [20, 25], // min, min
      [30, 40],
      [30, 50],
      [35, 55]
    ]
  }, {
   linkedTo: 'main',
    data: [
      [25, 35], // mid, max
      [40, 50],
      [50, 80],
      [55, 70]
    ]
  }, {
   type: 'scatter',
    xAxis: 1,
    name: 'Eployees',
    data: [
     [8, 30],
      [8.5, 25],
      [9, 15],
      [9.5, 28],
      [10, 33],
      [10.5, 25],
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/enqLmpd8/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter

Comment: Thanks, Wojciech Chmiel!  That's essentially what I was looking for. I appreciate your time in responding.